# Calculate image size when using setCompoundDrawables for EditText

Tags: android, android-layout

When I am add icon like below:

```
etComment = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_comment);
Drawable img = getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.warning );
etComment.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( img, null, null, null );
```

[image]
[image]

The icon resizes EditText. How can I calculate img size and put it into EditText without EditText resize?

Thanks!

---

> **FunkTheMonk** 
>   Use setCompounDrawables() instead of setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds() - you'll have to set the bounds of the drawables manually.

I don't understand how to calculate Bounds manually. I have got height and width of EditText:

```
etComment = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_comment);
Drawable img = getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.warning );
int size = etComment.getHeight();
img.setBounds(0, 0, size, size);
etComment.setCompoundDrawables( img, null, null, null );
```

but I have different results in different screen sizes. How I can calculate correct size and padding of icon? Could you please help me?

Answer (score 8):

I think you can use different size of pics for different screens and use getMinimumWidth to set Bounds.But I did not try it before , may be it is not appropriate for .9 patch.

When you use setCompoundDrawables , you need code like :

```
Drawable img;
Resources res = getResources();
img = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_img);
//You need to setBounds before setCompoundDrawables , or it couldn't display
img.setBounds(0, 0, img.getMinimumWidth(), img.getMinimumHeight());
btn.setCompoundDrawables(img_off, null, null, null);
```

Comment: worked fine with image re-sizing in button, thanks a lot

Comment: what is **img_off** in last line?

Answer (score 5):

I've found the solution in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8655456/447558) post.

```
Drawable dr = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.warning);
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) dr).getBitmap();
Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(this.getResources(), Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 35, 35, true));

txtValue.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(d, null, null, null);
```

HTH,
Milton

Comment: 'java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable' I am getting this error can you please tell me where i am wrong?

Comment: @sumitmehra you should ask a separate question to get an answer. You were getting this error because you were loading an SVG as bitmap drawable.

Answer (score 3):

Use [setCompoundDrawables()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawables%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29) instead of setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds() - you'll have to set the bounds of the drawables manually.