# How to set image size when using setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds()?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-drawable

I need to set image above text in tabs in Tab Layout. So I set image in my `TextView` using setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds but I don't know how give size for my image.

I tried to give size like this:

```
Drawable dr = ContextCompat.getDrawable(MainActivity.this, R.drawable.mobile_icon);
    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) dr).getBitmap();
    mobile_drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 50, 50, true));

    TextView tabOne = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
    tabOne.setText("Mobile");
    tabOne.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0,mobile_drawable,0,0);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(tabOne);
```

But it gives me this error:

```
Cannot resolve method setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(int,android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,int,int);
```

I also tried

```
tabOne.setCompoundDrawables(0,mobile_drawable,0,0);
```

but it also not working?

So how to give image size when using setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set drawable size programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4609456/set-drawable-size-programmatically)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Check this out**

```
Drawable img = ContextCompat.getDrawable(MainActivity.this,R.drawable.btn_img);
// You need to setBounds before setCompoundDrawables , or it couldn't display
img.setBounds(0, 0, img.getMinimumWidth(), img.getMinimumHeight());
btn.setCompoundDrawables(img, null, null, null);
```

[Calculate image size when using setCompoundDrawables for EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8198561/calculate-image-size-when-using-setcompounddrawables-for-edittext)

Comment: `getDrawable` is deprecated ........we can use ` img = ContextCompat.getDrawable(MainActivity.this, R.drawable.mobile_icon);` in place of `res.getDrawable`.

Comment: what is **img_off** in last line?

Comment: @AnoopM please remove `Resources res = getResources();` line and replace `img_off` with `img`

Answer (score 8):

## The accepted answer is outdated and buggy...

You cannot set drawable size using `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds`

Instead, you need to set it using `setCompoundDrawables` like this

```
Drawable img = ContextCompat.getDrawable(yourContext, R.drawable.yourImgId);
img.setBounds(0, 0, yourSize, yourSize);
yourTextView.setCompoundDrawables(img, null, null, null);
```

Comment: Just for your clarification - I went through the edit history. Since `Nov 5 '15 at 7:27` itself `setCompoundDrawables` used in the accepted answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me in VS.Xamarin

```
text = parentView.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.text);
Drawable img = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.id.resource_id);
img.SetBounds(0, 0, 20, 20); 
text.SetCompoundDrawables(img, null, null, null);
```