# How to fit image width inside textview width programmatically in android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to add a bitmap image inside a textview  which is encoded and stored in DataBase useing base64 encode. i am using the following code

```
byte[]img= Base64.decode(cur.getString(2),Base64.DEFAULT);

 Drawable qDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(ctx.getResources(),BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(img,0,img.length));

 question.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null,null,qDrawable,null);
```

this code work good but

> the problem is the image width  doesn't fit textview  width

I tryied to use ScaleType in xml but the textview doesn't have this property like imageview so how I can fix this issue with textview

Comment: You are setting `CompoundDrawable` . instead of this use a `ImageView` with `TextView`.

Comment: `"doesn't fit textview width"`so what does it fit? you called `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds` so it uses its own intrinsic size - see `TextView#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds` method source implementation

Comment: @pskink part of image is hidden but if i rotate the screen i see image perfectly

Comment: see `TextView#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds` method source implementation

Answer (score 0):

You need to resize your bitmap before setting it. Use `Drawable.setBounds()` and `View.setCompoundDrawables()` to achieve the desired width and height.

Example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33538681/450356).