# How to set height and width of the Icon of a Key on Keyboard

Tags: java, android

I created my `Keyboard`. I need to show `icon` on one `Key`.

```
 Keyboard.Key key;
 key = this.getKeys().get( 0);
 Drawable icon = context.getResources().getDrawable( iKeyIcon); // iKeyIcon - id of my file resource with icon
 key.icon  = icon;
```

How can I set programmatically its height and width?

Comment: I find solution on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4609456/android-set-drawable-size-programatically

Comment: Drawable icon = context.getResources().getDrawable( iKeyIcon);Bitmap bitmapIcon = ((BitmapDrawable) icon).getBitmap();
icon = new BitmapDrawable( context.getResources(), Bitmap.createScaledBitmap( bitmapIcon, context.getResources().getInteger( R.integer.iConfigIconSize),context.getResources().getInteger( R.integer.iConfigIconSize),true)); key.icon = icon;