# Where is this drawable located?

Tags: android, call, drawable

I used the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8655456/1974738), and compiled everything successfully.

However, I cannot find out how to use the drawable that I have just created. Here is my code:

```
Drawable dr2 = getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_manage);
Bitmap bitmap2 = ((BitmapDrawable) dr2).getBitmap();
Drawable f = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap2, 256, 256, true));

private Integer[] menu_icon = {
    android.R.drawable.f,
    // I can't figure out how to call Drawable f
};
```

After converting the drawable to the `Drawable f`, I am unable to find out how to recall the resized drawable.  I have tried using all possible locations in my code as to where it may be (/res/drawable and a few other locations).  However, I am unable to compile no matter how I try to call Drawable f.   Any help would be greatly appreciated!

(And no, I have eight elements in that array, but only copy+pasted one)

Comment: Please take some advice.  You need to start with the basics of learning what software is, how software works, basic programming (basic in terms of complexity, not language) , OOP then Java/Android.  In that order.  If you don't understand what an instance of a class object is, you are going to struggle at every turn.  It will save you time to invest in the fundamentals.  The return on that investment is far greater than the approach you are now taking.

Comment: It was good natured, and clearly badly pitched, but I am amazed that you would think that creating a new instance of a bitmap drawable would somehow create a file in your project structure.  That would be some amazing side effect on the documented constructors ;)  Anyway, to use it, just assign the instance to any property of type BitmapDrawable on one of your UI view objects.

Comment: Well, I was actually thinking more of a temporary file, like a cache, so I was looking for some temp folders.  However, I reverted mt mindset, and realized that I could just call the image through a function, which is why I came here to SO.  Cheers mate!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It exists only in memory, not anywhere on disk.  You can't reference it by id.  Instead, you need to call versions of functions that take a Drawable rather than ones that take an int resourceID.

Comment: Depends what you want to do with it.  For example, if you want to use it in an ImageView, you'd call setImageDrawable instead of setImageResource.  Pretty much every function should have a version that takes a drawable, but the name may change slightly.

Comment: You should probably get images of the right size, scaling images up tends to leave ugly artifacts.  But if thats all you want to do, set a fixed size in your gridview cell's xml.  Then set the scale type to fit.  Android will automatically scale them for you.

Comment: <ImageView android:layout_width=100 android:layout_height=100/>  That would make it resize the image to 100x100 and scale it.