# How to fit width and height of a Drawable object in android?

Tags: android, html, textview, drawable, spannablestring

I have a `TextView` with Html content and it has an `img` tag:

```
    textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(styledText, new Html.ImageGetter() {
        @Override
        public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
            Drawable drawable = Drawable.createFromStream(epubExplorer.readDrawable(source), source);
            drawable.setBounds(0, 0, drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight());

            return drawable;
        }
    }, null), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

The image pops out of TextView due to its large width.

How can I fit it?

Comment: You need to fit the drawable in imageview correct.?

Comment: Hi @RahulAgrawal I have the img tag in my html content and I have no ImageView.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44142192/3251783) may help you

Comment: It didn't help me